# How do I reformat a column of numeric data to have five rows between specific values when these specific values are spaced differently daily?

Tags: excel, vba

example: * (loading bays are door assignments in a warehouse) in this column of data, Loading bay M1-1 has 3 rows until next loading bay value of 152, continuing downward from bay 152 to 151, there are 3 rows, same to bay 150, however from bay 150 to bay 149, there are 4 rows. I need to keep these bay numbers exactly 5 rows apart; (pattern being -  BAY, 4 rows of data, BAY, 4 rows of data, BAY etc...) by inserting a blank row IF the next bay is LESS THAN 5 rows from the next bay.

I have a properly formatted template of each bay#, then 4 rows, then the next bay#

```
M1-1
5
0.00%
7
152
164
0.69%
38
151
0
0.00%
0
150
870
3.65%
17
136
149
2,438
10.22%
34
350
>>>>
```

correctly formatted column I created with index and match: How do I retrieve the 3 rows of data below the constantly changing row spacing and copy into my correctly formatted column.

```
M1-1
0
0
0
0
152


0
0
151
0

0
0
150


0
0
149
0

0
0
148
```

My question and problem can seemingly be solved by inserting a row based on EACH bay# and how many rows until the next door. This needs to be fluid as the values change daily sometimes 3 spaces, sometimes 4. My result MUST be 4 rows then the next bay.

Not sure if I am asking correctly and will greatly appreciate ANY recommendations.
I am by no means an Excel expert, I solve problems often in odd ways and this I just have not been successful.

Comment: So Bay# syntax is both `<letter><digit>-<digit>` and a three digit number?  Are bay numbers always consecutive (ie, Bay 150 will always be followed by Bay 149 and not say, 136)?  How are you informed of the dynamic data changes - do you get new individual values, or is the entire column replaced?

Comment: I'm working on this when I can ... it's a bit of a pet project.

Comment: doors are 101 - 209, the alpha numeric doors are consecutive within the column.  this data originates from a PDF that is cut/pasted into a spreadsheet. I have a macro that eliminates all un-needed text. the problem arose when the format of the pdf changed and zeros pasted as blanks. It was not always so., a zero always pasted as a zero, preserving the format of door then 4 rows then door.  now the format changes every day, causing irregular spacing (rows)